# PYQT5 frameless window. on button pressed -- "showMinimized()" doesn't work

Tags: python, function, pyqt, pyqt5

the "MINI" function has the purpose of minimizing the window when the appropriate button is clicked.
needless to say it doesn't work it doesn't give me any kind of error, I really don't know how to do it

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import win32com.client as win32

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
#more code before
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget_7, clicked=lambda: self.mini())
        self.pushButton_3.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_3.setText("")
#more code after

    def mini(self):
        w = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        w.showMinimized()

if "__ name__" == '__ main __':

    import sys
    import salvataggioicone_rc
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_MainWindow()
    w = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ex.setupUi(w)
    statusbar = w.statusBar()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I tried putting "w.showMinimize() in the section "if **name** == '**main**':" and it works, but as soon as I put it inside the "MINI" function it does nothing

Comment: Where did you put that `mini` method? Please provide a valid [mre] (and also ensure that you're properly [format code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) by checking the post preview before submitting modifications.

Comment: i'm sorry it's the first question I ask and I didn't know how to change the layout, I updated the question, now it should be clearer

Comment: Regenerate that file with pyuic and **never edit again**, then follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) by creating a new python file as you *main* one script, create a subclass of QMainWindow by following what explained in the above link (I suggest you the multiple inheritance approach), add `mini` there and `self.showMinimized()` in it, finally connect the `clicked` signal of the button to `self.mini` in the init. Then look for tutorials about signals and slots, like [this one](//zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/eventssignals/).